# XPath optimization to select a node if it does not have an ancestor

Tags: xml, xpath, pmd

In very simple terms, I would like to write an XPath 1.0 query that selects `10` but not `15`.  `15` should not be selected since it has an ancestor `ArgumentList`.

Here is the XML.

```
<IfStatement>
   <Expression>
      ...
         <PrimaryExpression>
            <PrimaryPrefix>
               <Literal Image="10"/>
            </PrimaryPrefix>
            <PrimarySuffix>
               <Arguments>
                  <ArgumentList>
                     <Expression>
                        ...
                           <PrimaryExpression>
                              <PrimaryPrefix>
                                 <Literal Image="15"/>
                              </PrimaryPrefix>
                           </PrimaryExpression>
                        ...
                     </Expression>
                  </ArgumentList>
               </Arguments>
            </PrimarySuffix>
         </PrimaryExpression>
      ...
   </Expression>
</IfStatement>
```

Here is the XPath query I am using...

```
(//IfStatement | //ForStatement | //WhileStatement)
/Expression
//*
/PrimaryExpression
/PrimaryPrefix
/Literal[not(ancestor::ArgumentList)]
```

The `//*` is required because of the unknown number of nodes in the hierarchy represented by the `...` in the XML.

The problem is that `ancestor::ArgumentList` is a slow operation.  I would like to write the XPath query like the following.

```
(//IfStatement | //ForStatement | //WhileStatement)
/Expression
//*[not(self::ArgumentList)]
/PrimaryExpression
/PrimaryPrefix
/Literal
```

The problem is that `//*[not(self::ArgumentList)]` does not prevent from selecting `15`.

What do I put after `//*` to prevent from selecting `15` due to `ArgumentList`?

Comment: Any reason to want to use XPath 1.0? XPath 1.0 is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PMD…

Comment: Is ` <ArgumentList>` always a descendant of `<PrimarySuffix>` only or can it also be a descendant of `<PrimaryPrefix>` as well? More generally, what distinguishes the locations of the "bad" `Literal`s from the good ones?

Comment: @Johnco I tried using some XPath 2.0 features.  Maybe I do not understand what I am doing; however, I am unable to use these features properly.  If someone can show a XPath 2.0 query that works in PMD, then I will accept that for an answer.

Comment: @JackFleeting This is coming from PMD.  PMD parses Java code into an AST of XML nodes.  To answer your first question would require that I understand the requirements of PMD's AST.  I do not.  As for your second question, I am trying to implement a general purpose rule to replace `AvoidLiteralsInIfCondition` that flags using literals in the conditions for `while`, `for`, `return` and ternary operator.  If the literal occurs in an argument list, then it is "okay" but if it is in a condition then it is "bad".

Comment: @Johnco: Do you mean that XPath 1.0 *only* or all versions of XPath are deprecated in PMD?   It would be an odd decision to support XPath 2.0 but not XPath 1.0.

Comment: Only XPath 1.0 is deprecated. The plan is to support 2.0 and add support for 3.0 and 3.1. This is actually what Saxon supports underneath (1.0 support is through another dependency which is discontinued). For more info see https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/1687

Comment: @Johnco: Moving to Saxon shouldn't be a reason to deprecate XPath 1.0.  Something's odd there.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//Literal[not(ancestor::ArgumentList)]
```

will select `Literal` elements that do not have an `ArgumentList` ancestor,

```
<Literal Image="10"/>
```

but not

```
<Literal Image="15"/>
```

as requested.

Comment: The problem is that `ancestor::ArgumentList` is a slow operation.  I am trying to replace that with something faster.

Comment: I'm surprised that ancestor::ArgumentList should be a slow operation, but you haven't said what XPath engine you are using. On a small document I would expect the cost to be dominated by the cost of parsing and compiling the XPath expression; on a large document I would expect the search of the descendant axis to take much longer than the search of the ancestor axis. Do you have any measurements to back up your claim?

Comment: @Nathan: Unsubstantiated statements (*`ancestor::ArgumentList` is a slow operation* ???) about the unmeasured performance of unspecified libraries risks misleading future readers.   Either provide measurements to justify your claim, or withdraw it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With XPath 2.0 you could also do

```
//Literal except //ArgumentList//Literal
```

but there is no reason to expect that this is better than the 1.0 solution using the ancestor axis. It all depends on the chosen XPath processor, of course,

Comment: Not sure this merits much attention, but I thought you might find [deprecation of XPath 1.0 support due to a move to Saxon (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269121/xpath-optimization-to-select-a-node-if-it-does-not-have-an-ancestor/60270393#comment106630008_60269121) to be as strange as [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269121/xpath-optimization-to-select-a-node-if-it-does-not-have-an-ancestor/60270393#comment106751391_60269121).

Comment: I don't know anything about PMD, but it doesn't seem odd to me that a product that supports XPath 2.0 should want to withdraw support for XPath 1.0, in the sense that you can no longer use the few queries (like `1 < 2 < 3`) that are allowed in 1.0 but not in 2.0.